# redir everything in a folder, but not certain pages - htaccess

Tags: htaccess

How can I edit my `.htaccess` file to redir everything in a folder, except 3 pages on that same folder

Redir everything here: `/site/` but exclude `/site/page-1.html` `/site/page-2.html` `/site/page-3.html`

my htaccess

```
# Redirect to site page
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ ./site/index.php
</IfModule>
```

*Those files dont exist as physical files...*

Here is the situation, I mess up with my canonical tags, then google indexed a lot of wrong pages in that time... (around 1300 pages) of those 1300 pages only 3 pages is the correct ones.... Thats why I wanna keep these 3 pages and redirect to a 404 page everything else

Comment: Do the 3 files `/site/page-1.html` etc. exist as physical files? To clarify, you are wanting to _modify_ your existing rule block or create an additional redirect? Your exitsing rule block is an internal rewrite, not a redirect - hence the confusion. And what are you wanting to _redirect_ to exactly? To `/site/`?

Comment: Why don't you just change your index file to return a 404 status except for those 3 URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and redirect to a 404 page everything else

You shouldn't "redirect" to a 404 - simply serve the 404 directly.

For example, the following should go *before* your existing directives:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /custom-errors/e404.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/page-1\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/page-2\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/page-3\.html$
RewriteRule ^site/ - [R=404]
```

For any *direct* request that starts `/site/` (except for the 3 URLs mentioned) then serve a 404. Edit `/custom-errors/e404.php` (or your existing Apache 404 document if you have one) to customise the response.

The first condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that we only process direct requests and not rewritten requests by the front-controller below.

However, this means you are only accepting 3 URLs to your front-controller (the code you posted in the question). ie. You only rewrite these 3 URLs to `/site/index.php`. So, instead of the above, you could simply make sure that the request is one of these 3 URLs before rewriting.

For example, modifying your existing front-controller:

```
# Redirect to site page
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/page-1\.html$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/page-2\.html$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/page-3\.html$
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ ./site/index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is the opposite logic of the first solution. It rewrites only when it is one of the specified URLs, instead of redirecting when it isn't.

Or, as @Stephen suggested in comments, "change your index file [ie. `index.php` / front-controller] to return a 404 status except for those 3 URLs", and not change your `.htaccess` file at all. I'm curious why your site isn't already returning a 404 for these (presumably invalid) URLs?